# Hosts connected to DD-WRT router running radvd get IPv6 addresses but can't communicate

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, ipv6

I'm trying to get IPv6 working on my local network.  I know my ISP (Comcast) supports it because anything connected to the modem/router combo I rent from them gets assigned an IPv6 address and communicate using the protocol (can connect to ipv6.google.com and gets 20/20 on http://test-ipv6.com/).

However when I connect my own router (Netgear WNDR3800, if it's relevant) running DD-WRT to the Comcast modem/router combo none of the hosts can communicate over IPv6, although they get assigned IPv6 addresses in the prefix I was delegated by Comcast.

It seems to fail before it even leaves the LAN. Attempting to ping the IPv6 address of the router returns "Destination host unreachable".  My guess would be that I'm missing a route somewhere, but I am not familiar enough with IPv6 or routing to know how to test that theory or how to resolve it.

Technical details:

Router: WNDR3800 running DD-WRT v24-sp2.  Its IPv6 configuration looks like this:

[image]

Router ifconfig:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# ifconfig
ath1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [redacted]
          inet6 addr: fe80::224e:7fff:fe74:13da/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:188122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:227134 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:26587839 (25.3 MiB)  TX bytes:211385503 (201.5 MiB)

br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [redacted]
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224e:7fff:fe74:13d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:190093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:217213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:24491040 (23.3 MiB)  TX bytes:204922896 (195.4 MiB)

br0:0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [redacted]
          inet addr:169.254.255.1  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [redacted]
          inet6 addr: fe80::224e:7fff:fe74:13d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:569599 (556.2 KiB)  TX bytes:3297349 (3.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:4

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [redacted]
          inet addr:10.0.0.59  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:601:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:13d9/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::224e:7fff:fe74:13d9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:216381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:181622 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:202350364 (192.9 MiB)  TX bytes:25482727 (24.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:5
```

ipconfig from Windows 8.1 host connected to the router:

```
C:\Users\seth>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601:601:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:75c3
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2601:601:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:2b13
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18b5:93d6:d9db:75c3%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

(unrelated interfaces removed from output. lo, VMWare, etc)

Comment: Why is dhcpv6 disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound Are you referring to Dhcp6s in the dd-wrt screenshot? Turning it on causes no changes..

Comment: The "modem/router combo" that you mention might not support multiple layers of prefix delegation.

Comment: @kasperd can you elaborate? My understanding is with radvd that's not necessary.

Comment: also other people have gotten it working with similar Comcast router/modems so it must be possible, I'd think.

Comment: According to all sources, enabling IPv6 doesn’t load the IPv6 module, and enabling Radvd doesn’t guarantee that it will start. There exist detailed descriptions on how to get it working: (1) [IPv6 on v24](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6_on_v24), (2) [Native IPv6 in dd-wrt](http://kirkiancomputing.co.uk/2015/11/01/native-ipv6-in-dd-wrt/) (detailing 4 years of efforts!), (3) [DD-WRT IPv6 (tutorial)](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6). Verify first against these sources.

Comment: @Seth Router advertisements will allow endhosts to get an IP address from a router which has already acquired a prefix for the LAN. But that router must first have acquired that prefix from somewhere. It could either be statically configured on the router, or it could have acquired the prefix from an upstream DHCPv6 server through prefix delegation.

Comment: @harrymc already seen two of those, but the second one I hadn't found in all my searching. It looks helpful, I'll see if it gives me any tips that fix the issue.

Comment: @kasperd yes, and as you see in the question I have it configured that way. Dd-wrt receives an address from the modem/router combo and uses radvd to advertise that to it's LAN.

Comment: @Seth You have manually specified a prefix in the `radvd` configuration. But I don't see anything in the question demonstrating that that prefix is actually the one you received using prefix delegation. In fact I don't see any evidence that the router even received a delegated prefix. Moreover in the `ifconfig` output I cannot see which interface is LAN and which is WAN.

Comment: @kasperd hm, guess I left that out of the question, but the modem/router combo told me what prefix Comcast had delegated for me to use.  `eth1` is the WAN interface.

Comment: @Seth What do you mean the modem told you? We need to know both the prefix delegated from Comcast to the modem and the prefix delegated from the modem to DD-WRT.

Comment: @kasperd The prefix delegated from Comcast to me is shown in the radvd configuration box in the dd-wrt screenshot. That's the only delegation I have.

Comment: When you connect (what?) w/ipv6 and are able to connect to google's ipv6 address, what settings are you using and on what system (linux or Windows)?    Why are you wanting to use the dd-wrt router (i.e. your linux box could do routing for your local boxes)? Do you know that the dd-wrt router will route client-packets to other clients?  Have you tried looking at what the network traffic looks like with 'wireshark'?  (A great tool to become familiar with).  So, you want to have the winbox talk to the linbox through the dd-wrt router via ipv6?  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Part of the problem here, for me, anyway, is I don't know enough about what the dd-wrt box supplies or is doing.  It may be that it won't forward packets between clients by default, or it may need to be set to do that.  The router will need to have routes for your local network to be shared/resent to the other local hosts (and not, presumably, out to the internet -- which may be where they are going).  But the unknowns are why I wondered why pref for dd-wrt -- vs. using a separate network card on linux for local traffic.

Comment: That way you can know what your 'router' (your linux box) is doing and can be _reasonably_ certain that traffic over your local net isn't sniffable from the internet (though local traffic CAN be forwarded to internet, with reasonable caution it can be prevented, as well).

Comment: @Astara default settings. Tried both Linux and Windows. Why should I use a dedicated linux both with dual NICs (assuming I had one, I don't) when I have a router? The same router works wonderfully with IPv4.

Comment: @Seth: Did I say dedicated?  My linux box *is* my router, but it's not even close to being dedicated (conversely, it handles *everything*). Anyway, sorry, It looked to me like you had 'eth0' and 'eth1', which would usually indicate 2 NIC's.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @astara no worries. Sorry if I came across short. Indeed it's a dual band router with a 4 port switch and the WAN port so it should appear to have multiple NICs :)

Comment: @Seth The only prefix I see in that screenshot is in the custom radvd config. And I have no idea where you got that value from.

Comment: @kasperd from the modem, which got it from my ISP.

Comment: @Seth So the modem says it got a `/64` delegated from the ISP?

Comment: @kasperd yes.. that's how prefix delegation works.

Comment: @Seth That's not how it is supposed to work. Which brings us back to my first comment: It might not support multiple layers of prefix delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and clarifications in the comments we have learned that what you have is a `/64` delegated from your ISP to your modem. The modem is using that `/64` as link prefix on the connection to the DD-WRT router. And if there is a switch on that connection (possibly built into the modem), then you can connect more devices to that link.

What you don't have is a prefix delegated to DD-WRT. The prefix just isn't delegated that far.

You have manually entered the prefix in the DD-WRT configuration as if it was delegated. However that is not the case so essentially you have configured all devices connected to the DD-WRT to spoof IP addresses which do not belong to the network segment to which they are attached. Maybe they will be able to send packets to the internet, but they will never get a response.

**How to solve it**

You have a few options. The cleanest solution would be to have multiple layers of prefix delegation. The ISP is supposed to delegate a shorter prefix to your modem. For the usage you describe it makes no difference how long that prefix is, as long as it is a `/63` or shorter. For the following example I will assume the ISP has delegated `2001:db8:feed::/48` to your modem.

The modem can split the `/48` into subnetworks and send router advertisements for `2001:db8:feed::/64` and delegate `2001:db8:feed:100::/56` to DD-WRT. Then DD-WRT can use that delegation to send router advertisements for `2001:db8:feed:100::/64`. This would leave both routers with plenty of free blocks of address space which they can subdelegate or use for additional interfaces. For example if you have Ethernet with multiple VLAN or WiFi with multiple SSID, you would have a total of 256 `/64` which DD-WRT could send router advertisements for.

**What if the modem does not support it**

Multiple layers of prefix delegation is (AFAIK) not widely supported. So if your modem doesn't support it, the solution above won't work. It is also possible that your ISP ignores RFCs about what prefix length to delegate and only give you a `/64` when they were supposed to give you something shorter, in which case you also wouldn't be able to use the solution explained above. But there is an alternative.

If you configure one of the two routers to operate as a bridge rather than as a router, you will have one less IP segment on the path between your LAN and the internet. That means you only need a single `/64` delegated to get a working configuration, and you will only have a single layer of prefix delegation, so support for multiple layers of prefix delegation is no longer required.

Judging from your question it sounds like it is the modem where you would want bridging. Then the ISP can delegate a prefix directly to your DD-WRT router, which it can use on the LAN.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem like I can get anything smaller than a /64, although Comcast is working on it (since 2014 make me laugh) but bridging does seem to solve my problem. I didn't really want anything to do with the Comcast router anyway. I'll give that a shot later when I have a minute. Thanks for helping me figure this out.

Comment: I'm still very confused about one thing though. What's the point of radvd then?

Comment: @Seth `radvd` will tell individual machines on a single network what the prefix of that network is, which router to use to get to the internet, and optionally a few other pieces of information such as DNS servers. In the simplest cases it can completely remove the need for DHCP. So `radvd` can provide IP configuration from routers to individual machines, but it cannot do more advanced stuff such as providing the necessary information for other routers or tell machines which time zone they are in. If you want those things, you need DHCPv6.

Comment: that seems redundant.. :/ Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Seth It is understandable that having both SLAAC and DHCPv6 seems redundant. However SLAAC alone is enough to provide client machines an IP address and teach them what the local prefix is, where their gateway is, and which DNS servers to use. That covers everything that the wast majority of users ever needed from DHCP. DHCPv6 gives you more advanced features such as prefix delegation which is a feature that IPv4 never had. If you wanted to do the same with IPv4 you'd need to manually configure static addresses on the routers.

Comment: well I'll give you the bounty, but I couldn't get it working. When I turned on bridge mode I couldn't for the life of me get any DNS working.. I don't have more time to troubleshoot now. But it seemed to get the addressing right.

Comment: Well I did get it working somehow. I don't remember what I did. However it still seems odd that eth1 has a public IPv4 address and br0 has the global unicast IPv6 address and a *private* IPv4 address. I'm having issues contacting my server over IPv6 from outside the network. Full ifconfig output: https://paste.debian.net/970535/. Does that look odd to you?

Comment: @Seth Why do you say "eth1 has a public IPv4 address"? I only see `10.0.0.59`. And why do you say "br0 has the global unicast IPv6 address"? I only see `fe80::224e:7fff:fe74:13d8`. There is nothing unusual about seeing global unicast IPv6 address and private IPv4 address on the same interface. Ideally you should have global unicast addresses for both IPv4 and IPv6, but it's been more than a decade since we had enough IPv4 addresses to do that.

Comment: Did you read my paste or the output of the question? The paste in my previous comment is what it looks like after bridging the modem.

Comment: Oh. It expired. Oops, my bad

Comment: OpenWrt will re-delegate smaller prefixes out of a delegated prefix. It might be worth switching firmware if this is needed.